# How do I use a variable in another if statement in a Bash script?

Tags: bash

So let's say, I have an if statement that looks like this:

```
if [[ $line == *'<=='* ]]; then
   VARIABLE="${line%%<==*}"
   OBJECT="${line#*<==}"
   echo $VARIABLE
   echo $OBJECT
fi
```

I need to create an if statement that uses the variable object from that last if statement, however when I add this to the code:

```
if [[ $line == $VARIABLE ]]; then
   echo $OBJECT
fi
```

Full code:

```
line="greeting <== hi"

if [[ $line == *'<=='* ]]; then
   VARIABLE="${line%%<==*}"
   OBJECT="${line#*<==}"
elif [[ $line == $VARIABLE ]]; then
   echo $OBJECT
fi
```

It does absolutely nothing at all. How can I fix this?

Comment: The variables isn't scoped to the `if` statement. It's available outside. Do whatever you want with it.

Comment: let me edit the post.

Comment: @JohnKugelman edited, so basically it still didn't do anything at all

Comment: John is correct as far as I can see.. if you run `echo $OBJECT` outside of the if block it should still be resolved.

Comment: For me it's not... @wooooooo

Comment: If `$VARIABLE` is the substring extracted from `$line`, `[[ $line == $VARIABLE ]]` will not hold. Please post your combined code of the two `if` statements with `$line` assigned to some actual value.

Comment: Thank you for the update, but what is your desired output anyway?

Comment: My desired output is to print out 'hi' using that method.

Comment: The `if` statement and the `elif` statement are alternative, meaning only either of  the two (or none) is executed. You may be expecting the both are executed in sequence.

Comment: Or are the variables `$VARIABLE ` and `$OBJECT` predefined to some values prior to the `if` statement?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243078/discussion-between-1bl1zzard-and-tshiono).

Comment: Simple solution, add `OBJECT=` below `line="greeting <== hi"` so `OBJECT` exists outside the `if` statement. You will need to set it to something in your script.

Comment: Hi there. We don't use `[Solved]` title hacks here. Please either accept an answer below (by ticking it) or write a self-answer and accept/tick that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

I had to set variable to:

```
VARIABLE="${line%%<==*::-1}"
```